# Visual Studio high CPU usage

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I've got problem with Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate edition. My cpu usage peaks top after search on entire solution or undoing pending changes and doesn't go down until I turn off VS. Does somebody have similar experience?

Comment: My experience is that VS2010 can get rather luggish. I suggest you report your problem using Miscrosoft Connect.

Comment: It's interesting, that this is going only after this two operations. It started about 3 days ago.